# Conversion algorithm needed.

Tags: exponential-function, square-numbers

I just started an online course in math, and have a problem with an exercise.
I don't know what this type of math is called in English, so please forgive me for the bad title (and tags).

The question:

I know that

$$x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = (x+y)^2.$$

But I need an explanation for how to reach the result.
If someone would explain it to me like I am $5$ years old, I would grateful.

Edited:

Btw. I do know how to do it the way around:
$$(x+y)^2 = (x+y)*(x+y) =$$
(Now comes the conversion I don't know how to do it the other way around)
$$(x*x)+(x*y)+(y*x)+(y*y) = ....$$

Comment: By 'the other way around', do you mean that you know how to show that (x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy?

Comment: Yes, indeed. My math book only explains how to do it one way.

Comment: Okay, so you could also note that: a = b if and only if b = a.  Therefore, (x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy if and only if x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = (x+y)^2.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm following. I edited the last part of my question to show, what I mean. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(x + y) ^2 &= (x + y) \ (x + y) \\
&= x \ (x + y)+ y \ (x + y) \\
&= \cdots
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Before showing you how to arrive at your solution, let's start with what you already know:

$$\begin{align}(x + y) ^2 &= (x + y) \ (x + y) \\
&= x \ (x + y)+ y \ (x + y) \\
&= x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 \\
&= x^2 + y^2 + xy + yx\\
&= x^2 + y^2 + 2xy
\end{align}$$

The process for showing the inverse will be to walk the steps backwards.

$$\begin{align}x^2 + y^2 + 2xy &= x^2+y^2 + xy + xy \\
&= x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 \\
&= x \ (x+y) + y \ (x + y)\\
&= (x + y)(x + y) \\
&= (x + y)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for clarifying things a little more.